# Django Signals: How to signal for first entry in table

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I am creating django applications(applications in django terminology) where 1st application inserts data in a table and 2nd application picks one item from table, processes it and finally remove from table. It continues to do so until all entries are processed. When all entries are processed it stops. It start again when a new entry is made. So it is like consumer-producer problem.

How can I use django signals to start 2nd application when a first entry is made into the table?

Comment: Applications? Why don't you simply override the save method? When you insert a new item in the table, you process it (= run the 2nd "application" code)! You need a timer? Are you using remote servers? You need to check it first (as human)? To be honest, I really hope this is homework or something, because your method of doing what you are doing doesn't seems server-IO-friendly to me!

Comment: @StefanNch I mentioned "consumer-producer" so it does not mean it is homework :). Well, I can override save method but it will start processing as soon as I save. I want to process it in first come first serve basis. Because processing one item is CPU intensive. I can not afford to run all in parallel.

Comment: @StefanNch please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You can add auto incrementing integer field in the model. Consumer can just get records order by this field, process the item and delete it.

Comment: @Rohan yes that makes it FCFS but it does not stop it from parallel processing.

Comment: Signals doesn't execute in parallel. The subscribed methods will execute when the signal rises sequentially so what's the point to do it like that instead of with `save`?

Comment: You may want to look at celery or django-huey.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yes! thats exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much. Could you please post it in answer so that I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution to the problem is [django-celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) as mentioned in the comment. django-celery provides a task queue and process tasks without blocking request. So while inserting a new item if producer finds table empty, it signals to consumer with post_save method and handler start the task and stops when all finished.